# Blob data and impact on Replication on Oracle 11g RAC

Tags: oracle11g, blob, replication

We are using Oracle 11g, the application generates data in sets of about 250K bytes each. I want to use oracle blobs to store it.

The table would be simple as

```
{
  id number, 
  data blob
}
```

Have following questions

1. How does the tables with blob data impact oracle replication?
2. Is there any issues with storing data as blob?

Comment: Exactly what technology are you talking about when you talk about "Oracle replication"?  Simple materialized views?  Multi-master materialized views?  Streams?  GoldenGate?  Change Data Capture (CDC)?  Logical standby?  Active DataGuard?  Some tool outside the database?

Comment: Understand there is many ways to do this, I am not aware of what strategy will be taken. Assuming third party tools are not used, does having table with blobs have problems with any of these strategy e.g. Streams Replication, Materialized views, Data guard?